# Converting positive number values to boolean TRUE in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to sum up all the entries based on several specific conditions.

The goal is to count all entries that have a 'yes' ticked in them in cells J or K or L or M and have '1st' in H

This is the formula I'm currently using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((('J2:J100="yes") + (K2:K100="yes") + (L2:L100="yes") + (M2:M100="yes")) * (H2:H100="1st"))
```

This almost works.

The problem is that I want to count a record only once if he has a yes for any of the 4 cells (J,K,L,M) and not multiple times. So for example, if a single record has 'yes' marked in both cells K and L and has 1st in H he will be counted twice instead of once.

This is because the SUMPRODUCT function would evaluate to 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 * 1  which is = 2

I'm thinking if there's a way to convert the first part of the function I've written to be transformed in to a boolean so that any positive value is tread as a 1 and any negative is treated as a False it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `>0`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((('J2:J100="yes") + (K2:K100="yes") + (L2:L100="yes") + (M2:M100="yes")>0) * (H2:H100="1st"))
```

Now

```
(0 + 1 + 1 + 0 > 0) * 1
```

Will become

```
1 * 1
```

which is `1`

Comment: The idea being here is that when we compare it to greater than 0 it automatically changes the expression to a boolean true or false ? That's smart and it does the job but I'm wondering how else can  I approach this? Is using sumproduct the best for this type of comparision and is there a function that would convert the balues to boolean?

Comment: Since they are contiguous you can probably use MMULT but that can get complicated: `=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(--(J2:M100="yes"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(J2:M100)^0))>0) * (H2:H100="1st"))`  There is a point that this is easier, but it is around 3 or 4 columns.  BTW I just typed that formula without testing. It may have typos.

Comment: BTW, If one has Office 365 with `BYROW` we can substitute the `MMULT` part with `BYROW(J2:M100,LAMBDA(a,SUM(--(a="yes"))))>0`

Answer (score 1):

`>0` obviously will work nicely and likely faster than a function would.

It might not be too obvious just what's the idea, either to you (in two years) or someone else who might be maintaining the spreadsheet someday.

Excel has a function, `OR()`, that covers this situation very nicely. Instead of four separate comparisons producing 1/0, being added, being compared, etc., it simply, in a clear to anyone, now and forever, does the four comparisons, and produces one single 1 or 0 as its output.

Well, not directly:  it produces a TRUE or FALSE, but multiplying it by the column H item coerces its result into a 1 or 0 and lets the multiplication succeed. (This is what is happening when you see people use the `--` or `*1` methods to coerce the same effect. But ANY multiplication does the trick, not just with those, so they are not necessary.

But people do love the (0+1+1+0) route, and it's not an issue for them, but if you desire a simple other method, `OR()` fills the bill.